# Command Binding in UserControl used as ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command, commandbinding

I have a `Listbox` with a `UserControl` as the `DataTemplate`. This `UserControl` has a `Button` to remove that item from the list.

```
<ListBox x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" >  
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Views:FileItem/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The `ItemsSource` is defined as:

```
ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> m_fileViews = new ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>();
```

Here is the `UserControl` simplified:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.FileItem">
   <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">
      <TextBlock x:Name="FileName" Text="{Binding FileName}" />
      <Button Content="Remove"/>
   </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

When the user clicks the `Remove` button, it should remove this item from the `ObservableCollection`.

The problem is, the `DataContext` for each `ListBoxItem` is a different ViewModel than the ViewModel that holds the `ObservableCollection`.

I'm not sure how to bind the `Remove` button to an `ICommand` in the "parent" ViewModel. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bind the button to an ICommand in the UserControl's ViewModel, then send a message across to the parent ViewModel using loosely-coupled messaging (available in most Mvvm frameworks, like [MvvmFoundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/))

Let the parent VM register for the 'remove me' message, and update the ObservableCollection accordingly...

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. I was worried about a couple more scenarios I was going to face in development, and the Mediator pattern solved all of them.